# array formula for summing values down columns

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a table with an unknown number of columns (the columns are read from a transpose of some rows elsewhere in the spreadsheet) and I'm trying to apply an array formula to include a sum over each of these columns.

I feel like I could do this with a bycol and lambda or something, but I'm struggling to figure out how to choose the correct ranges to have given rows from variable columns. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Example sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zHMN7YiXCZKnLgrcyonMmKIicLWn9MmwokRMLUdCke4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a range to expand vertically until the end of the spreadsheet, you omit the last row. For example `A1:A`.

If you want a range to expand horizontally until the end of the spreadsheet you omit the last column. For example `A1:1`.

If you want a range to expand both vertically and horizontally until the end of the spreadsheet, you omit the last row and enter **ZZZ** as the last column. For example `A1:ZZZ`.

So here's what you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:2,E2:2-BYCOL(E4:ZZZ,LAMBDA(c,SUM(c))),))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I like this, feels easier to parse and understand than the other solution. So sheets can't go higher than column ZZZ, so in effect a range ending :ZZZ includes all possible cells to the right and below the top left cell of the range? And presumably ending :40000 does the same as the upper limit of rows?

Comment: Ahh wait I might be incorrect with the rows, one website said there's no limit on rows, there's just limits on columns and total cells?

Comment: The website is correct. There's only a limit on columns and total cells. The limit on rows depend on those.

Answer (score 2):

*You may try:*

```js
=bycol(E4:99999,lambda(Σ,let(Λ,index(2:2,column(Σ)),
                if(and(Λ="",counta(Σ)=0),,Λ-sum(Σ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice but couldn't Λ just happen to be zero even though numbers were present in a column?

Comment: Valid point... added a *if()* check now instead of masking out all zero outputs.